# Solving list of numbers

Tags: real-analysis

How should I solve a problem? Tell me please

Comment: Where is the list? What are we supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to determine the order of the list with only this information, for at least two reasons:

1. With few exceptions, there are multiple ways to achieve the same sum with different combinations of numbers, so even if you can determine that (for example) a certain set of 3 numbers sums to 9 it be any of $(1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 5), (2, 3, 4)$.
2. Even if you can determine the sum of a group of numbers, you won't know what order they're in. So if you knew that the set of numbers was $(1, 2, 6)$ the actual order could be $(2, 1, 6)$, or $(6, 2, 1)$, or several other options.

This is definitely going to be an issue for at least the first 21 numbers in the list - the information you have will never let you distinguish between any reordering of those values.